# magento get recent updated row for a custom extention

Tags: magento

i have made a custom plugin for magento in which i want to get the last updated row details from database . But its giving me the very first row . My code is

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('campaign_campaign/campaign')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
$keys = array_keys($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```

suppose i added a data 2 hours back and again added a data just now . then its getting the 1st data row instead of latest one how can i get the latest one and i only one to show the last updated latest row .

Comment: first sort by updated time then get afirst first record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('campaign_campaign/campaign')
         ->getCollection()
         ->setOrder('update_time', 'DESC'); //where update_time is `column_id`
         $collection->getSelect()->limit(1); // Where 1 is your limit if you set 2 then you get 2 data from collection
```

Let me know if you have any query